# How to replace the elements of a range less than k with k?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

How do I replace the elements in the range of an array greater than k by k when the number of queries are high?
Given that each query is given by the form l r k; where [l...r] is the range of the array.

Comment: Can you show what you have done to do this ?

Comment: I've used the naive approach of comaparing and replacing with k. Since the number of queries are very high, the complexity is m*n. I want an efficient algorithm to do this.

Comment: I want the updated array after all the queries have been implemented

Comment: @himanshutiwari  Please show your code .

Comment: @ameyCU for(i=0; i<m; i++)
      {
   scanf("%d%d%d",&l,&r,&k);
    
   for(j=l-1; j<r; j++)
        if(k<a[j])
         a[j] = k;
    }

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth m is the number of queries and n is the size of the original array.

Comment: i forgot to mention that k is always less than equal to 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my first answer created big thread of comments I'm going to combine everything in new answer.

We are going to use Segment Tree as helper data-structure which will be used to answer this question: what is the minimum on range [l, r]. Initially all segment tree nodes will be filled with some "Infinity" numbers which can be 201 in your problem (since all K are lower then 200 based on your comment).

Once we read our input array (lets call it A) we are going to process queries:

- for each query [L, R, K] we are going to update our segment tree: try to set new minimum K on range [L, R]. That could be done with O(LogN) using lazy propagation. Here is a great example http://se7so.blogspot.com/2012/12/segment-trees-and-lazy-propagation.html
- now we need to build final array. We are iterating over each index in our array and replace it with A[i] = min(A[i], minimum_on_range(i, i)). That will take N * Log(N) steps

Total complexity of that approach is **M * Log(N) + N * Log(N)**

Comment: That is a good explaination, but can you explain how can i  "set new minimum K on range [L, R]". Can this approach still be used if all the elements of array A are initially 201 and we are interested only in the final array?